PUG + VUE(2,3) + Quasar
Давно обратил внимание, что при использовании PUG постоянно проблема. Пишешь код и приложение просто перестает работать. Необходимо перезапустить сервер и после этого начинает работать. Связано точно как-то с PUG!
Кто сталкивался? Что делать?
